# Facebook Audience Network with other network in mediation

Tags: android, mobile-ad-mediation

I am currently using facebook audience network ads. Is it possible to add other ads network in mediation?

Comment: it is possible if you are using something like dfp, then you can add mediation networks.

Comment: What is dfp?? Any link please.

Comment: Can i still use it if my adsense and admob account is disabled?